# Parsing a perl regex

Tags: perl

```
if ( $_ =~ /^(\d+)_[^,]+,"",(.+)"NR"(.+)"0","",""/ )                    
{ }
elsif ( $_ =~ /^[^_]+_[^,]+,"([\d\/]+)","[^"]+","[^"]+","[^"]+","[^"]+","[^"]+",
               "[^"]+","[^"]+","[^"]+","[^"]+","[^"]+","[^"]+","[^"]+",.+/x    )
```

in the first time, is it repeat digit one or more time, then _, then repeat any char not equal to , one or more times, what does the ,"", do? does it look a whitespace or is comma an escape char of some sort, sort of confused and don't have the ability to test it on this machine. are there generally commas in regex?  also the ^ at the very beginning, it it an anchor or negating the whole thing ?

2nd statement is worse

Comment: Try using a tool like [Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/), it might be able to help you.

Comment: `,"",` is just what it says. A comma, followed by two quotation marks, followed by a comma.

Comment: Is anyone else entertained by the fact that the 2nd regex ends with a `/x` only to allow a new-line and not to document the noise?

Comment: I would prefer to read something like: `$quote = qr/"[^"]+"/; ... /...($quote,){12}/;`

Comment: thanks guys very helpful perl regex is quite a thrill

Answer (score 6):

The CPAN module [YAPE::Regex::Explain](https://metacpan.org/module/GSULLIVAN/YAPE-Regex-Explain-4.01/Explain.pm) can be used to parse and explain Perl regexes that you don't understand. Here is the output for your first regex:

```
(?-imsx:^(\d+)_[^,]+,"",(.+)"NR"(.+)"0","","")

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  _                        '_'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^,]+                    any character except: ',' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ,"",                     ',"",'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .+                       any character except \n (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  "NR"                     '"NR"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .+                       any character except \n (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  "0","",""                '"0","",""'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can use the module to parse your second regex as well (I won't dump it here since the explanation will be very long and very redundant.) But if you want to give it a shot, try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use YAPE::Regex::Explain;

my $re = qr/^[^_]+_[^,]+,"([\d\/]+)","[^"]+","[^"]+","[^"]+","[^"]+","[^"]+",
           "[^"]+","[^"]+","[^"]+","[^"]+","[^"]+","[^"]+","[^"]+",.+/x;

print YAPE::Regex::Explain->new( $re )->explain;
```

Answer (score 2):

- It's all as you say.
- `,"",` matches a comma followed by two double-quotes followed by a comma.
- Commas aren't significant in regex patterns.
- `^` is an anchor (start of string). It only negates when the first character of a character class (`[^...]`).

A better approach would be to parse the line into fields using [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV_XS), then match against the values obtained.

```
if (   my ($num) = $row->[0] =~ /^(\d+)_[^,]+\z/
   and $row->[1] eq ""
   and ...
) {
   ...
}
elsif (... ) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: got it so does the anchor apply to the entire expression? or just the next character or item or whatever

Comment: I don't think that comment makes sense. Can you find an example where this distinction matters? `(\d+)` matches against a string of numerals, which must be at the start of the string. `_` matches against a `_` character, which must be immediately after the number. This would be true anyway: the regex must match a contiguous substring. For example, `'123 foo _' =~ /(\d+)_/` fails even without the `^`.

Comment: @user2521358, when a `^` is encountered a pattern, it will match if current position is zero, and it will fail otherwise. (If `/m` is in effect, it will also match is the character before the current position is a newline.)